# Set a Live Tile Image to a Web Image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to update my tile with images retrieved from the internet. In my app I attempt to set the Live Tile background image to one of these images. However, simply using the online URL doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out how I am supposed to save and work with the image.

How could I accomplish this in Windows Phone 7.1?

An example image is

[image]

Comment: Try to first download the image to localStorage and the use it for live tile.

Comment: Alright, did some fun playing around with it and got it to work. Not so proud of the implementation, but it works. Thanks, Typist.